# Android database date type setViewBinder

Tags: android, date, sqlite

I am wondering about using `setViewBinder`. When I try to this, all columns change same date even it has data. How can I edit each column, which is related date, not every column?
I think that I have to modify the `setViewBinder` part.
Could you help me?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent intent) 
{
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
   fillData();
}

private void fillData()
{
   cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllItems();
   startManagingCursor(cursor);
   String[] from = new String[] {FridgeDbAdapter.KEY_NAME,    
                                FridgeDbAdapter.KEY_EXPIRED_DATE};
   int [] to = new int[] {R.id.fridge_name_txt, R.id.fridge_expired_txt};
   SimpleCursorAdapter data_row = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.fridge_row,
   cursor, from, to);

   //It makes crash the list which is making all same date..
   data_row.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

   //How can I bind the data with only specific date column?
   public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int column) 
   {
      TextView tv = (TextView) view;
      String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("expired_date"));
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  date = df.format(cal.getTimeInMillis());
  tv.setText(date);
  return true;
  }
   });*/
   setListAdapter(data_row);
}
```

***** I edited setViewBinder.. however, it is shown the date every column, not specific column. And date is shown 01-01-1970, not like 12/11/2011..
How can I do?**

```
data_row.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int column) 
{
if(column>=0)
   {
TextView tv = (TextView) view;
    long date=cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("expired_date"));
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(date);
    String date_format = String.format("%1$td-%1$tm-%1$tY", cal);
tv.setText(date_format);
return true;
    }
  return false;
  }
```

});

[image: Original List]

[image: Result after setViewBinder]

Answer (score 0):

it is caused by this code

`String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("expired_date"));`

you should do smthing like this

`String date = cursor.getString(column);`

next you have to check if column == cursor.getColumnIndex("expired_date")
and do formatting only if it's true in other case you sould setup tv with data from date string

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is that you never are parsing the date you are getting from the database.

Try

```
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int column) 
   {
      TextView tv = (TextView) view;
      String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("expired_date"));
      tv.setText(date);
      return true;
  }
```

If the date from the DB isn't formatted how you want it to be formatted then:

```
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int column) 
   {
      TextView tv = (TextView) view;
      String dbDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("expired_date"));
      SimpleDateFormat dbDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("****db date format***");
      SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("****output format***");
      Date date = dbDateFormat.parse(dbDate);
      tv.setText(outputFormat.format(date));
      return true;
  }
```

Comment: When I use your coding, it happened error here, Date date = dbDateFormat.parse(dbDate);. they said use try catch, and date has to initialized. then I put Date date == null, and I used try catch. However when I debugging, tv.setText(outputFormat.format(date)); it is error again.. how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

About date types you can find there: 
[Android database date type setViewBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487683/how-to-convert-date-format-in-android)