# how to convert date format in android

Tags: android, date

I am getting date into string in `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS` format.I want to change it into the `mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` and also it will show AM and PM how can I do this.please help me

Thank you

Comment: I have created a simple method to do this. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/40042733/4531507

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To get AM PM and 12 hour date format use `hh:mm:ss a` as string formatter WHERE `hh`  is for 12 hour format and `a` is for AM PM format.

*Note:* HH is for `24` hour and hh is for `12` hour date format

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
            String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
```

**Example**

```
String date = "2011/11/12 16:05:06";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS");
        Date testDate = null;
        try {
            testDate = sdf.parse(date);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
        System.out.println(".....Date..."+newFormat);
```

Comment: nice answer, helped me a lot..was making mistake `HH:mm:ss a`

Comment: Isn't using hh also gives you `0` for `12`? I upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the same kinds of any date operations.

```
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"); 
SimpleDateFormat DesiredFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS a");   
                                                             // 'a' for AM/PM

Date date = sourceFormat.parse("2012/12/31 03:20:20");
String formattedDate = DesiredFormat.format(date.getTime());  
// Now formattedDate have current date/time  
Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `android.text.format.Time` to the conversion. You can pass the time as text and it will return you the time in desired format by using `timeInstance.format("")`;

you need to provide formatter.

Refer to following:
Time : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html
Formatter: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html

you can use any combination of formatter string to work with it :)

Answer (score 1):

just use the Time class. Try something similar to this.

```
Time time = new Time();
time.set(Long.valueOf(yourTimeString));
```

If you really need a Date object just try this.

```
Date date = new Date(Long.parse(yourTimeString));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use SimpleDateFormat or DateFormat for this here is the example

```
SimpleDateFormat gsdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
try{
    Date d = gsdf.parse("2011/12/13 16:17:00");
    System.out.println("new date format " + sdf.format(d));
}catch(Exception){
     // handle exception if parse time or another by cause
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getFormatedDate(String strDate, String sourceFormate,
        String destinyFormate) {
    SimpleDateFormat df;
    df = new SimpleDateFormat(sourceFormate);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = df.parse(strDate);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    df = new SimpleDateFormat(destinyFormate);
    return df.format(date);

}
```

and use like

```
getFormatedDate(strDate,
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "mm/dd/yyyy")
```