# Formatting System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: android, date, formatting

I am trying to format the following time to hh:mm:ss:

```
long elapsed;
elapsed = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000);
```

What is the way for doing this?

Comment: Check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487683/how-to-convert-date-format-in-android

Hope this will help you

Comment: Take a Look At [How to convert Milliseconds to “X mins, x seconds” in Java?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
long elapsed;
elapsed = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000);

String display = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", elapsed / 3600, (elapsed % 3600) / 60, (elapsed % 60));
System.out.println(display);
```

And let me know what happen..

Comment: Look at [Express a duration in term of HH:MM:SS](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/ExpressadurationintermofHHMMSS.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Androids version of [`DateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html):

```
DateFormat.format("hh:mm:ss", elapsed);
```

Note that elapsed should be in milliseconds, so you should remove the `/1000`.

Comment: if we're talking about elapsed time, better using `kk` in place of `hh`, or 0 hrs will be shown as 12.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for that?
From that page an example with multiple formats:

```
 String[] formats = new String[] {
   "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
 };
 for (String format : formats) {
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
   System.err.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
   sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
   System.err.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
 }
```