# Solving Parse Date Exception

Tags: java, android

i have a string "12/3/2014 12:00:00 AM" and i want to cast this string in date which have format like this "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

```
@DatabaseField(columnName="out_date",dataType=DataType.DATE_STRING,format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date out_date;
```

above is the object to get value from date string

```
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
outlet.setOut_date(formater.parse(json.getString("outletDate")));
```

after i using like the error occur java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ... (at offset 2) how to solve that problem thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Conversion steps :

1. Create `date` object from your date format.
2. Target date format provide to `SimpleDateFormat` class constructor.
3. Parse `date` using `SimpleDateFormat`.

The code provided convert `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` to `dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format.

```
try {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS a");
    Date date = sdf1.parse("12/3/2014 12:00:00 AM");
    String format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date);
    System.out.println(format);

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Error : `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ... (at offset 2)` indicates that you are using wrong date format to parse your sting.

Answer (score 0):

Based [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487683/how-to-convert-date-format-in-android), you need something like this. First convert your string in its present format to a date object, then reformat the date object.

```
String date = "12/3/2014 12:00:00 AM";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS a");
Date testDate = null;
try {
    testDate = sdf.parse(date);
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
System.out.println(".....Date..."+newFormat);
```